# subpixel rendering problems with grid

Tags: responsive-design, subpixel

i've run into this wierd problem with a fluid grid. Everything looks good in chrome and firefox, but the grid wont align on Ios and desktop safari. I realise that this is because of the different ways the browsers render subpixels. My question is if anyone has a workaround for this?

see a working example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eFyIl